# How to have separate legends for size and fill in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use a code similar to this, I get two separate legends for **fill** and **size**. However, I don't want the **fill** legend to show the points and the **size** legend to show the background.

```
ggplot(data=Temp1) +
geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=K,y=ImpactX,group=Area,fill=Area,size=ImpactX),show.legend=T,
stat='identity',position=position_dodge(0.8)) +
geom_point(mapping=aes(x=K,y=ImpactX,group=Area,size=ImpactX),
color='black',fill='transparent',shape=19,
position=position_dodge(0.8),show.legend=T,na.rm=T) +
scale_size_continuous(name='Size',range=c(1,4))
```

Here is my sample data ([**LINK**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcchaxdccbuqr30/Test.RData?dl=0)). Just contains a data.table, **Temp1**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of theme and some guide_legend with override.aes.

```
ggplot(data=Temp1) +
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=K,y=ImpactX,group=Area,fill=Area,size=ImpactX),show.legend=T,
             stat='identity',position=position_dodge(0.8)) +
    geom_point(mapping=aes(x=K,y=ImpactX,group=Area,size=ImpactX),
               color='black',fill='transparent',shape=19,
               position=position_dodge(0.8),show.legend=T,na.rm=T) +
    scale_size_continuous(name='Size',range=c(1,4)) + 
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white",linetype = 0)) +
    guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes =list(fill = "white"))) + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
```

[image]